# Will there be conflict if try to connect two MS SQL servers with same name and having same database name over TCPIP in LabVIEW?

Tags: sql-server, labview

I want to connect multiple SQL servers over TCP/IP with same server name and having same database name. I'm not able to change the server name or database name because the same names are used by testing softwares (LabVIEW) running on local machines. If I change the server names testing softwares(LabVIEW) does not work. So will there be any conflict if i connect all database having same server name over TCP/IP in LabVIEW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your servers IPs dynamic assigned? If not you can try to connect using IP instead of the server name.

Comment: Yes I did the same thing, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server alias to connect to different SQL servers using the same name:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?

Comment: Thank you. I have used IP address instead of server name and it is working